# udp hole-punching fails on virtualbox's NAT network

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I was testing hole-punching feature of strongswan with virutalbox's NAT network, but an error happened:

```
[sudo] password for bluven: 
tcpdump: data link type LINUX_SLL2
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL2 (Linux cooked v2), snapshot length 262144 bytes
10:02:55.430425 enp43s0 B   ARP, Request who-has 10.40.10.180 tell 10.40.10.168, length 46
10:02:55.430446 enp43s0 Out ARP, Reply 10.40.10.180 is-at c0:25:a5:3a:22:86, length 28
10:02:55.431092 enp43s0 In  IP 10.40.10.168.47648 > 10.40.10.180.48475: UDP, length 88
10:02:55.431147 enp43s0 Out IP 10.40.10.180 > 10.40.10.168: ICMP 10.40.10.180 udp port 48475 unreachable, length 124
10:02:55.433350 enp43s0 Out IP 10.40.10.180.33182 > 10.40.10.168.32768: UDP, length 88
10:02:55.435262 enp43s0 In  IP 10.40.10.168 > 10.40.10.180: ICMP 10.40.10.168 udp port 32768 unreachable, length 124
10:02:55.455493 enp43s0 In  IP 10.40.10.168.47648 > 10.40.10.180.48475: UDP, length 88
10:02:55.455494 enp43s0 In  IP 10.40.10.168.47680 > 10.40.10.180.48475: UDP, length 88
10:02:55.455557 enp43s0 Out IP 10.40.10.180 > 10.40.10.168: ICMP 10.40.10.180 udp port 48475 unreachable, length 124
10:02:55.455575 enp43s0 Out IP 10.40.10.180 > 10.40.10.168: ICMP 10.40.10.180 udp port 48475 unreachable, length 124
10:02:55.462016 enp43s0 Out IP 10.40.10.180.33182 > 10.40.10.168.32768: UDP, length 88
10:02:55.462293 enp43s0 Out IP 10.40.10.180.53372 > 10.40.10.168.32768: UDP, length 88
10:02:55.463936 enp43s0 In  IP 10.40.10.168 > 10.40.10.180: ICMP 10.40.10.168 udp port 32768 unreachable, length 124
10:02:55.466452 enp43s0 In  IP 10.40.10.168 > 10.40.10.180: ICMP 10.40.10.168 udp port 32768 unreachable, length 124
10:02:55.481386 enp43s0 In  IP 10.40.10.168.47648 > 10.40.10.180.48475: UDP, length 88
10:02:55.481387 enp43s0 In  IP 10.40.10.168.47680 > 10.40.10.180.48475: UDP, length 88
10:02:55.481432 enp43s0 Out IP 10.40.10.180 > 10.40.10.168: ICMP 10.40.10.180 udp port 48475 unreachable, length 124
10:02:55.481442 enp43s0 Out IP 10.40.10.180 > 10.40.10.168: ICMP 10.40.10.180 udp port 48475 unreachable, length 124
10:02:55.490814 enp43s0 Out IP 10.40.10.180.33182 > 10.40.10.168.32768: UDP, length 88
10:02:55.490824 enp43s0 Out IP 10.40.10.180.53372 > 10.40.10.168.32768: UDP, length 88
10:02:55.492815 enp43s0 In  IP 10.40.10.168 > 10.40.10.180: ICMP 10.40.10.168 udp port 32768 unreachable, length 124
10:02:55.493639 enp43s0 In  IP 10.40.10.168 > 10.40.10.180: ICMP 10.40.10.168 udp port 32768 unreachable, length 124
10:02:55.507903 enp43s0 In  IP 10.40.10.168.47680 > 10.40.10.180.48475: UDP, length 88
10:02:55.507949 enp43s0 Out IP 10.40.10.180 > 10.40.10.168: ICMP 10.40.10.180 udp port 48475 unreachable, length 124
10:02:55.516542 enp43s0 Out IP 10.40.10.180.53372 > 10.40.10.168.32768: UDP, length 88
10:02:55.519175 enp43s0 In  IP 10.40.10.168 > 10.40.10.180: ICMP 10.40.10.168 udp port 32768 unreachable, length 124
10:02:55.526381 enp43s0 In  IP 10.40.10.168.47648 > 10.40.10.180.48475: UDP, length 88
10:02:55.538668 enp43s0 Out IP 10.40.10.180.33182 > 10.40.10.168.32768: UDP, length 88
10:02:55.551839 enp43s0 In  IP 10.40.10.168.47680 > 10.40.10.180.48475: UDP, length 88
```

But I checked and found this port 48475 is open:

```
sudo ss -upn  
Recv-Q                      Send-Q                                             Local Address:Port                                              Peer Address:Port                      Process                      
0                           0                                                   10.40.10.180:48475                                             10.22.53.102:4500                       users:(("VBoxNetNAT",pid=738900,fd=26))
```

How did this happened?

Answer (score 0):

The UDP socket displayed is connected, ie: the [`connect(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html) system call was used on it. The `connect(2)` manual tells:

> If the socket *sockfd* is of type `SOCK_DGRAM`, then *addr* is the
> address to which datagrams are sent by default, and **the only
>
> address from which datagrams are received.**

The UDP socket will ignore any received UDP datagrams not from the remote address 10.22.53.102 port 4500: these are thus rejected as usual by the OS with an ICMP error.

So the port 48475 while being technically open (a socket exists), is not open to anything else than its current peer, just as any client TCP connection from some random port toward a web server on port 80 or 443 is not considered open either.

---

Note: if you want to have the state displayed (`ESTAB` meaning in connected state), you can run this command using `-a` that can display all states and thus will prepend the state:

```
ss -aunp state established
```

or

```
ss -aunp sport 48475
ss -aunp dport 4500
```

Etc. The default is to display only connected states and thus not prepending `ESTAB`:

> When no option is used ss displays a list of open **non-listening**
> sockets (e.g. TCP/UNIX/UDP) that  have  **established  connection**.

To have

Comment: I think allowing non-peer to send packets to a random udp port is the point of hole-punching. After reading the explanation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#Methods_of_translation, I guess it might because the implemenation of virtualbox NAT network forbit it.